# bypass instagram checkout_point

Tags: php, android, instagram, instagram-api

I have app that logs in every couple hours on different servers and does some request on behalf of a business Instagram account via [private instagram api](https://www.google.com/search?q=private%20instagram%20api&oq=private%20instagram%20api&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3j0l2.3960j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). It's working well, but sometimes it gives me checkout point error and I have to manually open Instagram insert a code received via email or SMS. Cann't use such a service in production since this scenario could occur any time! Some long time ago it was just fine... Is there a way to bypass this checkout?

I guess they does this lock due to IP changes. Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

These are Instagram's security measures and only way to make sure these won't pop up is to use same useragent, device ids and IP. But you could use SMSPVA API which will help you automatically verify the accounts